# PYTHONprintout twice

Tags: python, sqlite

For my function, I would like to access db and get command from searching function of commands

This is my code:

```
x="create vlan"
y="global"

def readswitch(x,y):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        run= cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return read;

    import database
    print (database.readswitch(x,y))
```

now ,I can printout my answer but there are few mistake on the result as following :

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/tommy/PycharmProjects/2015122/database.py
[('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('vlan (number)',), ('name (vlan name)',)]
[('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('vlan (number)',), ('name (vlan name)',)]
```

Process finished with exit code 0

I printout my answer twice but I do not get it why I print twice.

Comment: Did you run that SELECT on the database using an SQL client?

Comment: this can't be your code. please show us a runnable, reproducible example.

Comment: @helpYou Yes , I have just read the sql statement wothout my function and it works with only showing one result but not two

Answer (score 0):

Have you double-checked the results of this query with the sqlite database query tool? Perhaps you have two records in the database that match.

```
SELECT command FROM switch WHERE function = 'create vlan' or type = 'global'  ORDER BY key ASC
```

P.S. You might want to fix the formatting of your question, it's a bit hard to read.

Comment: I have double-checked the result.I have tried to change the sql statement to use other table "router" and get a ospf command but its result is as following:

Comment: @Bullington-McGuir [('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('interface serial(number)/(number)',), ('ip ospf priority (number)',)]
[('enable',), ('configure terminal',), ('interface serial(number)/(number)',), ('ip ospf priority (number)',)]